# Rubik's Cube Master Algorithm

Tags: mathematics, rubiks-cube, algorithm

I've been thinking about this question for a while, but I have no idea how to approach it. I don't know what the answer is. The question:

**What is the shortest finite set of moves that, when repeated, will traverse every possible Rubik's cube permutation?**

There is no restriction on repetition of states, so long as it can be shown that for each permutation, if this set of moves is repeated long enough, it will eventually reach that permutation. Obviously not including any permutation not attainable through legal rubik's cube moves.

Comment: I guess the first question is, does a repeatable sequence of moves that traverses all permutations even exist?

Comment: I think we can definitively say yes for the base case of 0 repetitions (basically a set of moves that traverses every permutation) but beyond that I don't know. Intuitively this reminds me of the dragon curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve#.5BUn.5DFolding_the_Dragon)

Comment: The link posted http://bruce.cubing.net/ham333/rubikhamiltonexplanation.html explains a hamiltonian cycle which traverses all permutations without repetition, but I still think a simpler algorithm could be created if we removed the "no repetition" constraint

Comment: @Matt: That question asks about one possible repeating move that solves it. This asks about a *path* through the states of the Rubik's Cube. They're completely different.

Comment: @Deusovi in a sense they're the same though, as an algorithm that solves any permutation must by definition traverse every permutation.

Comment: @Slepz: That question only asks about one specific algorithm that will solve it if you only check for solvedness at the end of each repetition. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this one checks for being solved after every step.

Comment: @Deusovi oh I see you're right

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, as it asks about all permutations, not solving them